# Regular Expression for: 567,"this is a character, known as A"

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Help me to find Single regex for the strings:

1. 567,"this is a character, known as A."
2. 567,This is a character, known as A.
3. 567,"this is a character, known as (/r)
      A."

I have tried the following regex for this:

1.

```
^([0-9]+)[ ?]*,[ ?]*(?(?=")(("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*)(,("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*))*)|([a-z, a-z]*))$
```

2.

```
^([0-9]+),(["]{1}[a-z,a-z]*["]{1})$
```

Comments: **regex 1 works fine but gives 6 groups** as only 2 groups should be there.

Try following **link to check** 
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx
Select MultiLine to checked.

Comment: Seems you have included some one's comment in the last sentence

Comment: @Cdeez I think the OP is saying the regex should be verified against that particular regex tester.

Comment: What do you need to match? and what *shouldn't* be matched?

Comment: Do you want to search for similar strings in a larger string, or do you want to parse a string into two values (groups)?  Does the (/r) mean the A is on a newline,  or is it literal?  And is the period always present (and never embedded)?  If the match is to cross multiple lines , then you need some kind of character sequence to help identify the end.

Comment: @Les "*you need some kind of character sequence to help identify the end*" - wouldn't the closing quote mark the end of the line?

Comment: @James one of the examples has no quote marks

Answer (score 1):

This `regex` should do!

```
^(\d+),("?[\p{L}\p{P}\s\r]*"?)$
```

\p{L}->would match all upper-lowercase letters

\p{P}->would match all punctuations..

\s->would match space

\r->would match carriage return

Comment: This doesn't handle the scenario where the `A` is on the new line.

Comment: @James sorry but i didn't get you..

Comment: The OP has stated they need the regex to be able to handle scenarios where the text feeds onto multiple lines (see 3rd example). Your regex doesn't handle this, it isn't far away though...

Comment: @James the (.*?) would also consider carriage return..so no issues there

Comment: Have you tested it? Doesn't work for me on the 3rd example. See @Les answer which *does* work.

Comment: If you plug this answers pattern into my answers code example, you will see that both patterns "work" but give different results.  This pattern captures the trailing carriage return, while mine does not.  However, one should try to write the most general pattern he can so that it will work for ALL likely input.

Comment: Thanks All for putting suggestions. first of all i want to tell you that in Third string (/r) is Enter or you can say a new line. And @ Anirudha your regex works fine but i want a little more in this is: the string as: 567,this is an  op" OR String as:  567,"this is an op              should not match If quotes starts it should finish with quotes and no single quote should be allowed at start or end.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.  It assumes that the period is a consistent indication of the end of your pattern and that the begin and end quote are optional.

```
^(\d+),["]?([^.]*[.])["]?
```

The c# version of this would be...

```
            var data = @"567,""this is a character, known as A.""
567,This is a character, known as A.
567,""this is a character, known as 
 A.""";
        var pattern = @"^(\d+),[""]?([^.]*[.])[""]?";

        foreach (Match mx in Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group Count: {0}:  Group[1]: {1}, Group[2]: {2}", 
                         mx.Groups.Count, mx.Groups[1].Value, mx.Groups[2].Value);
        }
```

(Note: you will actually get 3 groups because group 0 is always the entire match, but otherwise you get the two groups you would expect)

By the way, this pattern is intentionally general.  It also works for input data like...

```
678, This is a character, known as 1.
```

Which isn't in the original requirement.  But it's reasonable to assume you've given a very limited data example and that other characters types would be possible in the data to search.  It is a balancing act to write a pattern that is sufficiently specific to rule out false positives, while not missing ANY legitimate matches.

Comment: Thanks All for putting suggestions. first of all i want to tell you that in Third string (/r) is Enter or you can say a new line. And @ Anirudha your regex works fine but i want a little more in this is: the string as: 567,this is an  op" OR String as:  567,"this is an op              should not match If quotes starts it should finish with quotes and no single quote should be allowed at start or end.